# How to take data from different classes and save them to db in one class by pressing save button?

Tags: iphone

I am doing an alarm app for iOS, but I am a bit confused in taking data from different classes and save them to db in controller class.

for taking name, I have Name class, for taking time I have Time Class, for taking ringtone type, I have Ringtone class, so I am taking different values for one alarmTable(sqlite table) and saving them to db on save button which is in Controller.

I thought to take from every class and save them to delegate variables, and then fetch in controller class, is it almost successful, but having trouble in saving again default values,

Can anyone guide me that what is logic behind this?

These are variables in appDelegate

```
NSString *name;
NSString *time;
NSString *repeat;
NSString *sound;
NSString *snooz;
NSString *soundFade;
NSString *volume;
NSString *vibrate;
NSString *soundName;
```

This is way of getting values from appDelegates

```
 -(NSString *) getName {
return name;
  }
 -(NSString *) getTime {
return time;
  }
   -(NSString *) getRepeat {
return repeat;
  }
  -(NSString *) getSound {
return sound;
   }
  -(NSString *) getSnooz {
return snooz;
   }
  -(NSString *) getSoundFade {
return soundFade;
    }
  -(NSString *) getVolume {
return volume;
  }
  -(NSString *) getVibrate {
return vibrate;
   }
```

and when I do assign values to these delegate variables, I do write in different classes are below

```
      AlarmProjectAppDelegate *delegate = (AlarmProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication      sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate setName:name_textField.text];//name_textField contain alarmname
```

and I do like this before adding to Database

```
AlarmProjectAppDelegate *delegate = (AlarmProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//data for databas for new alarm start
NSString *name=[delegate getName];
NSString *time=[delegate getTime];
NSString *repeat=[delegate getRepeat];
NSString *sound=[delegate getSound];
NSString *snooz=[delegate getSnooz];
NSString *soundFade=delegate.soundFade;
NSString *volume=[delegate getVolume];
NSString *vibrate= [delegate getVibrate];
```

Comment: Post some code to get exact pattern of your logic.

Comment: Yup, I will send you now, just 2 mints .

Comment: I have edited my question, hope you will get idea from this coding

Comment: I have few questions. 1. Are these values to be stored in a single table? 2. Are you looking for the sample code for database interaction?

Comment: Yes, these all are in single table(AlarmTable), and for GUI I have other table(GUITable),

Comment: I need help, so that I can easily get values from different classes and save them in one database,,,,

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, you have to do is...

1. Create a separate class for individual table and declare all columns of table as variable in it.

2. Whenever you want to insert into any table, just create an instance of that table class and set all the variables.

3.Finally, pass that instance to your insert query as a parameter and get values from that.

For example...Create a class for Alarm table as below.

**For master class, I'm modifying partial code. Assume it with name, time and repeat class.**
In **Alarm.h**

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface Alarm : NSObject {

        name *objName;
        time *objTime;
        repeat *objRepeat;
    }

    // sample code for master class.
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *objName;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *objTme;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *objRepeat;

    @end
```

In **Alarm.m**

```
    #import "Alarm.h"
    @implementation Alarm

    @synthesize objName;
    @synthesize objTime;
    @synthesize objRepeat;

    @end
```

Now, call your insert query as given below...

```
    - (void) InsertAlarmData : (Alarm*)objAlarm
    {
           name *objName = objAlarm.objName;
           time *objTime = objAlarm.objTime;
           repeat *objRepeat = objAlarm.objRepeat;

           NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT into Alarm(name, time, repeat) values ('%@','%@','%@')", objAlarm.objName, objAlarm.objTime, objAlarm.objRepeat];
        const char *sql = [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &dbaseConnection) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(masterDBase, sql, -1, &hydrate_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
            {
                int success = sqlite3_step(hydrate_statement);
                sqlite3_reset(hydrate_statement);
                if (success != SQLITE_DONE) 
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Database operation is not successful.." message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
                    NSLog(@"Error: failed to excecute query domain with message '%s'.",         sqlite3_errmsg(masterDB));
                }
            }
            else
            {           
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg (masterDB));
            }       
            sqlite3_reset(hydrate_statement);
            sqlite3_finalize(hydrate_statement);
        }
    }
```

To set values in Alarm class...

```
    name *objName = [[name alloc] init];
    objName.name = @"ABC";
    time *objTime = [[time alloc] init];
    objTime.time = @"5 AM";
    repeat *objRepeat = [[repeat alloc] init];
    objRepeat.repeat = @"After 5 mins";

    Alarm *objAlarm = [[Alarm alloc] init];
    objAlarm.objName = objName;
    objAlarm.objTime = objTime;
    objAlarm.objRepeat = objRepeat;
    [self InsertAlarmData:objAlarm];
```

Hope, you are getting my point exactly now.

Comment: you are making me laugh dear, can we talk something about this class?

Comment: Dear this class is feasible when you have to to save data in one class, but I have to extract from different classes, Like name from Name.m, and ringtone from Ringtone.m, and repeat from Repeat.m, so how can you apply same object in different classes :-P

Comment: There are many classes, name from Name.m, Time from Time.m, Repeat from Repeat.m, Sound from Sound.m, Snooz from Snooz.m, .....

Comment: Each column is from one separate class, so how you can apply your logic of single object, it will applied only when you have all values in one class, but here each column is from separate class.

Comment: As I told you, that is a sample code to get an idea. The same logic with little manipulation will do. You have to create a master class in which declare all classes and the same way as given above, pass the master class to your database interaction class and retrieve values individually.

Comment: What do you means Master Class?, specify code or expalanation please

Comment: The logic which you told me, I have been using in all my classes, for managing objects, but can you tell me master class, cz the above will not work in my situation, i am sure,

Comment: even after retrieving values from delegate, I am using same logic of data management, so that all columns be a part of one Object.

Comment: "You have to create a master class in which declare all classes and the same way as given above, pass the master class to your database interaction class and retrieve values individually." Please Specify it a bit more along with code, this is first time, I am hearing such thing, may be I will get something new from you, help dear

Comment: Please check the modified code with concept of Master Class. I have explain my point of you, hope now it make you smile in real sense. :)

Comment: Sir can't you see that you are writing name *objName; and when giving property, you writing it like (nonatomic, retain) NSString *objName;  Why NSString while it is an object of name class??

Comment: I don't know that either you will read this or not, but I am sure that there is still big problem between NSString and name class?

Comment: One more thing is that when you will do ObjectName.name in Master class, then it will return you null, because the object who took the name is different than the object to whom you are saving in database

Comment: Now, I would like to say only that the code is working perfectly at my end but the way you are replying, I don't think that you are able to understand the flow.!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3081/discussion-between-veer-and-iapple)